# How to properly use flask @auth.login_required in multi-files project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask, flask-httpauth

My Flask API REST server is becoming larger and larger so I decided to split methods (urls) into different sub files.

My previous version (single file app) worked with verify_password() callback function to override standard method as in this example: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/REST-auth/blob/master/api.py

Now, in my new multi file project, i need to make verify_password() function accessible from all @auth.login_required decorator in any single file but i cannot find a way to make it working.

How can I do?
Regards

```
    @auth.verify_password
    def verify_password(username, password):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username = username).first()
        if not user or not user.verify_password(password):
            return False
        g.user = user
        return True
```

Comment: As I mentioned elsewhere, the verify password function does not need to be accessible from the decorator, it just needs to be registered with Flask-HTTPAuth. You can leave this function in the place where you define your Flask-HTTPAuth instance for example. If you are getting specific errors it would be useful to see what those errors are, I can't really give you specific advice without knowing what errors you are getting.

Comment: Hi Miguel, thanks for your answer (and for your examples on web).
The only way i found to make verify_password reachable by all resource classes (files) is creating it as global function. Otherwise all password checking route only to the standard verify_password function on flask_httpauth module

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. The Flask-HTTPAuth package does not have a default `verify_password` function, this is a function that is provided by the application. As I said above, the function needs to be registered with your Flask-HTTPAuth instance, it does not need to be reachable elsewhere. I insist that if you are getting specific errors or wrong behaviors you should describe them in detail in your question.

Comment: @Filippico what did you do in the end? I have a same problem now

Comment: @11223342124 At the end (but i'm not so satisfied on it) i moved the main part of "verify password" function to a global class (just to make the shared code smaller), and the i copied this code to the top of each class

@ auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username_or_token, password):
    return global_function.verify_password(username_or_token, password)